# login on webpage only from the internet

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

First of all sorry if my question is dumb or if I use bad terminology but I'm totally new to web programming.

So, I've made an apache server on raspberry pi with few buttons on the webpage to controll lights in my room. I can access it with my home network ip `192.168.xxx.xxx` and from internet using my public ip `188.75.xxx.xxx`. (just to be clear - the raspi is connected to my router and in the router I'm forwarding port 80 to it)

I want to make some basic login form, but only if I'm connecting trough the `188.75.xxx.xxx` ip. And if I'm conencting trough the `192.168.xxx.xxx` the form will not show.

Is there any way to achieve this? 
Thanks,
Adam N.

Answer (score 2):

When the script is executed, check the IP address before showing anything to the user. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php) about the procedure. Once you have an IP address, you can parse it and see the first two groups. Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883413/parsing-ip-address-in-php) to do that. Then compare the numbers and decide to grant or deny permission to access the page. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297812/how-to-implement-a-login-system-under-php) you can read about login form in PHP. In pseudo code, that would look like that:

```
// this is pseudo code, don't try to run it - it will not work
$ip = get_ip();
$groups = parse_ip($ip);
if ( is_home_network($groups) )
{
    grant_permissions();
}
else
{
    request_login();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) Function with the validate filter `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP` and the flag filter `FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE`.

Code Example:

```
if ( filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE) )
{
    // is not a local ip address
}
```

I hope i could help you.